# Dynamically added event handler disables the previous one in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I am creating buttons dynamically in JavaScript.
Also adding dynamically an eventhandler to each button.
For the last button it works but the previous ones simply are not working any longer. Here's my small piece of code. What do I do wrong?

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
    var id = 0;

    function makeFunc(arg) {
        return function() {
            alert('selected ' + arg)
        }
    };

    function addElement() {
        document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML +=
            '<button id=\'id' + id + '\'>Button' + id + '</button>';
        document.getElementById('id' + id).onclick = makeFunc(id);
        id++;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="addElement();">Add Button</button>
    <p id="p1"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

it's also here: http://jsfiddle.net/q52a7fw0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `innerHTML` like

```
 document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML +=
            '<button id=\'id' + id + '\'>Button' + id + '</button>';
```

you **overwrite** exisiting event handlers.

Instead, you should create the element and append it

```
function addElement() {
  var button = document.createElement('BUTTON');
  button.id = id;
  button.textContent = 'Button ' + id;
  button.onclick = makeFunc(id);
  document.getElementById('p1').appendChild(button);

  id++;
}
```

```js
var id = 0;

function makeFunc(arg) {
  return function() {
    alert('selected ' + arg)
  }
};

function addElement() {
  var button = document.createElement('BUTTON');
  button.id = id;
  button.textContent = 'Button ' + id;
  button.onclick = makeFunc(id);
  document.getElementById('p1').appendChild(button);

  id++;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="addElement();">Add Button</button>
  <p id="p1"></p>
</body>
```